# How to create table with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to create table with javascript. I would like to ask user, for width and height of a table (1 cell is 1 unit). Then when table is created, if user clicks in to one of the cell, color changes. I have so code written, but I am pretty much stuck.

HTML CODE:

```
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <style>
        #chessboard{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse}
        td {width: 40px; height: 40px}

        tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {background: black}
        tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {background: black}
    </style>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">
    <div>
        <table id="chessboard">

        </table>
    </div>
</body>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
   var width = parseInt(prompt("Put width", "here"));
   var height = parseInt(prompt("Put height", "here"));

      function myFunction()
      {
         var tabel = document.getElementById("chessboard");

        for (i = 0; i < height; i++){
        var row = tabel.insertRow(i);
        };

        for (j = 0; j < width; j++){
        var celica = document.getElementByTagName("tr").rows[j];
        var x = celica.insertCell(j);
        };

        }
```

Comment: You're not appending anything to the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than looping over the columns you want in your row separately, try nesting the for loop.  It's much easier and means you don't have to clumsily look up the row again.

FYI, there is no getElementByTagName, only getElementsByTagName.

```js
  var width = parseInt(prompt("Put width", "here"));
  var height = parseInt(prompt("Put height", "here"));

  function myFunction() {
    var table = document.getElementById("chessboard");

    for (var i = 0; i < height; i++) {
      var row = table.insertRow(i);
      
      for (var j = 0; j < width; j++) {
        row.insertCell(j);
      }
    };

  }
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="script.js"></script>
  <style>
    #chessboard {
      border: 1px solid black;
      border-collapse: collapse
    }
    td {
      width: 40px;
      height: 40px
    }
    tr:nth-child(odd) td:nth-child(even) {
      background: black
    }
    tr:nth-child(even) td:nth-child(odd) {
      background: black
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body onload="myFunction()">
  <div>
    <table id="chessboard">

    </table>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: hmm i see, but i stil have problems with onClick event. How can change each cell color to red onClick?

Comment: Could you post that as a new question?